# Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto (vba ChartObjects.Add)

Tags: vba

Estoy intentado pasar imágenes a Outlook y he encontrado un código que lo hace primero exportando los rangos de Excel a imágenes, para hacer esto crea un objeto ChartObjects con el tamaño del rango seleccionado y luego lo exporta. Este es el **código original** desde el que comencé:

```vb
Sub createJpg(Namesheet As String, nameRange As String, nameFile As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Worksheets(Namesheet).Activate
    Set Plage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).Range(nameRange)
    Plage.CopyPicture
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.width, Plage.height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
    End With
    Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects(Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete

    Set Plage = Nothing

End Sub
```

Esto me ha funcionado y luego lo he convertido en bucle para hacerlo en varias imágenes, pero la segunda tenía unos tamaños muy raros así que revisando el código vi que era porque cogía los tamaños de otra hoja. Por tal motivo lo he cambiado todo y ahora este es el código actual:

```vb
Sub CrearImagen()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Col As Integer, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsR As Worksheet, wsM As Worksheet, _
    Imagen As Range, Fila, FirstRow, FirstCol, Hoja As Worksheet, sHoja

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Report Control Desk Activ.")
    Set wsR = wb.Sheets("Report Control Desk")

    LastRow = ws.Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Row
    Col = ws.Range("XDF3").End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set Imagen = ws.Range(ws.Cells(12, 2), ws.Cells(LastRow, Col))
    Imagen.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    With ws.ChartObjects.Add(Imagen.Left, Imagen.Top, Imagen.Width, Imagen.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export wb.Path & "\ImagenesMail\" & "Imagen" & i & ".jpg", "JPG"
    End With
    ws.ChartObjects(ws.ChartObjects.Count).Delete
    Set Imagen = Nothing

End Sub
```

Ahora me da todo el rato un error de

> Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto

El error me lo da en esta línea:

```vb
With ws.ChartObjects.Add(Imagen.Left, Imagen.Top, Imagen.Width, Imagen.Height)
```

¿Alguien podría decirme qué estoy haciendo mal por favor? He buscado en muchos foros ya y a mi parecer así es como se hace, pero no entiendo por qué me da el error.

Comment: y estan bien los valores de imagen??? es dificil saber q esta mal, tu codigo no puede probarse facilmente...

Comment: gbianchi, sí, lo he probado todo de hecho... en lugar de poner las medidas del rango, he puesto a mano valores de 10, 10, 10, 10 y me da el mismo error... no entiendo qué puede haber mal la verdad....

Comment: Quizás sería bueno que agregues el enlace al código original para que sea más sencillo ver qué fue lo que cambiaste

Comment: Hola mariano, en el código original no utilizan los objetos de worksheet ni de workbook, tampoco el de rango, viene dado de otra función. No obstante ahora edito.